# In windows RDP Can not connect to the Service with chromedriver in python exe

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, rdp

I created a python exe with pyinstaller. The program open the Chrome, and search a page.
It works on the development machine, and on other local computer.

It doesn't works on the RDP machine.

Error on RDP machine:

Message: Can not connect to the Service \192.168.100.37\media\Informatika\anyag\chromedriver

My Code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'\\' + r'192.168.100.37\media\Informatika\anyag\chromedriver') driver.get('http://192.168.100.195/simon_beta/autload.php')
```

Thx help!